# To get all rows from ElasticSearch query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have searched for answer to this several times and have found same question here also. But none really answers the question.
I know how to use size parameter in ES queries.
But If I don't know the size and I want to get ALL records of ES query (not just default 10 or even 50 000 records (with size), etc).
Desperately I have also tried to use size=* and size=0, if that could pass the limit and return unlimited amount of rows.

Pagination (that ES suggests) also doesn't help, because that is not suitable for the job.

Comment: What version of ES are you running?

Answer (score 0):

You need the [count api](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-count.html). Do your query against the count api, get the number of results, then set this number as your limit for the query, then run this against the normal search api to get all of your results.